# How can I compare against FileSystemRights using Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystems, acl

I want to check whether a given user has access to a given folder - by checking if they have "Modify" access assigned to them.

I thought that the PS for that would be:

```
(Get-Acl .\myfolder).Access | ?{$_.IdentityReference -eq "BUILTIN\Users"} |?{$_.filesystemrights.value -contains "Modify"}
```

But the final part of that isn't working - I get back no result.  But I know that they have Modify access - if I put in:

```
(Get-Acl .\myfolder).Access | ?{$_.IdentityReference -eq "BUILTIN\Users"} | select -ExpandProperty filesystemrights
```

then I get back:

```
Modify, Synchronize
ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
```

Is this because the FileSystemRights property is an enumeration?  And if so, how do I test against it?

Answer (score 7):

It's a type problem.  `(Get-Acl .\myfolder).Access[].FileSystemRights` is of type `System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights`.  It's not really displaying a string.  To make it a string, just use the `ToString()` method:

```
(Get-Acl .\myfolder).Access | ?{$_.IdentityReference -eq "BUILTIN\Users"} |?{$_.filesystemrights.ToString() -contains "Modify"}
```

Or you can use the bitwise comparison method.  However, it's very easy to confuse when you want to use this:

```
($_.FileSystemRights -band [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Modify) -eq [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Modify
```

With when you want to use this:

```
($_.FileSystemRights -band [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Modify) -eq $_.FileSystemRights
```

They have very different meanings.  For example, if you have Full Control, the former test is still true.  Is that what you want?  Or do you want to know when the `FileSystemRights` are *literally* just `Modify`?

Also, `[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]` is an incomplete enumeration.  In my environment, I found I needed this table:

```
+-------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|    Value    |             Name             |            Alias             |
+-------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
| -2147483648 | GENERIC_READ                 | GENERIC_READ                 |
|           1 | ReadData                     | ListDirectory                |
|           1 | ReadData                     | ReadData                     |
|           2 | CreateFiles                  | CreateFiles                  |
|           2 | CreateFiles                  | WriteData                    |
|           4 | AppendData                   | AppendData                   |
|           4 | AppendData                   | CreateDirectories            |
|           8 | ReadExtendedAttributes       | ReadExtendedAttributes       |
|          16 | WriteExtendedAttributes      | WriteExtendedAttributes      |
|          32 | ExecuteFile                  | ExecuteFile                  |
|          32 | ExecuteFile                  | Traverse                     |
|          64 | DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles | DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles |
|         128 | ReadAttributes               | ReadAttributes               |
|         256 | WriteAttributes              | WriteAttributes              |
|         278 | Write                        | Write                        |
|       65536 | Delete                       | Delete                       |
|      131072 | ReadPermissions              | ReadPermissions              |
|      131209 | Read                         | Read                         |
|      131241 | ReadAndExecute               | ReadAndExecute               |
|      197055 | Modify                       | Modify                       |
|      262144 | ChangePermissions            | ChangePermissions            |
|      524288 | TakeOwnership                | TakeOwnership                |
|     1048576 | Synchronize                  | Synchronize                  |
|     2032127 | FullControl                  | FullControl                  |
|   268435456 | GENERIC_ALL                  | GENERIC_ALL                  |
|   536870912 | GENERIC_EXECUTE              | GENERIC_EXECUTE              |
|  1073741824 | GENERIC_WRITE                | GENERIC_WRITE                |
+-------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

It's interesting to compare the output of these:

```
[System.Enum]::GetNames([System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]);
[System.Enum]::GetNames([System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]) | % { "$($_.ToString())`t`t$([System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]$_.ToString())`t`t$(([System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]$_).value__)";}
[System.Enum]::GetValues([System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]) | % { "$($_.ToString())`t`t$(($_).value__)";}
```

The `GENERIC` rights are not enumerated in the .Net class, but you will see that numeric value if you enumerate enough files.

Good luck!

Comment: Note that if you get two entries for the same user account on an ACL, that indicates the `GENERIC_` flags are present. For example, given two ACEs with `ReadAndExecute` and `-1610612736` respectively, the latter translates to `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_EXECUTE`.

Answer (score 2):

Got it:

```
(get-acl .\myfolder).Access | ?{$_.IdentityReference -eq "BUILTIN\Users"} | ?{($_.FileSystemRights -band [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Modify) -eq [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Modify}
```

It's both a bitwise comparison - and therefore you need to use "-band".

But "-band" will return true if *any* of the same bits are set in both enumerations.  And as even "Read" has several bits set (it's 100000000010001001) - some of which will match with "Modify", you need to also compare the result with "Modify" to make sure that the result is actually the same.

(Thanks to the comments below for getting me pointed in the right direction.)

Answer (score 0):

Updated new version.

Clarified version from Arco's comment.

With this version we're checking if the Modify bit is set.

```
(Get-Acl .\myfolder).Access | ?{$_.IdentityReference -eq "BUILTIN\Users"} |?{ $_.FileSystemRights -band [Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Modify}
```

The value__ property is the numeric bit set version.

Comment: How about this version?

Comment: That almost works - you gave me enough to get to it.
Because "Read" and "Modify" share _some_ bits, -band returns a "truthy" answer, when comparing them.  So you need to take the result of the -band and compare it with "Modify" to make sure it actually is Modify.